# Cyclomatic complexity of McCabe vs Yourself Drawing

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

So pretty much I was taught to work out the cyclomatic complexity like this [site does](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/cyclomatic_complexity.htm)
But then recently I found this thing that says Cyclomatic Complexity = ( 1 + ifs + loops + cases ). Are they the same? is the thing I read perfect for every case? As I'm wondering whether it would miss out on something or doesn't take something into account when calculating? From what I understand it seems fine but it just feels a bit simple compared to drawing out everything.

Also if I have a loop such as

```
while (a==b && c>d) {
}
```

would I say there is 1 loop there (comp = 1 loop+1) or would I say there is 3 (1 loop +1 test+1 test+1) due to the while a==b and the c>d test parts.
and how does that compare to say just

```
while(a>b) {
}
```

as I would assume that would have just 1 loop so (comp = 1 loop +1)
I would also assume it would be the exact same as a FOR loop in terms of complexity.

as

```
for(int i =0; i<12; i++){
}
```

it has just the single loop.

Lastly if I have something like code, while loop with no if statements or anything then end code.

If I drew the paths do I just have one path doing code>loop>endcode. Or do I have two paths being:

> 1) code>loop>endcode
>
> 2) code>endcode Imagine that loop is the FOR loop I wrote above for
>   example.

Apologies for all the questions, it seems to be loops in particular I'm super confused with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the flow path analysis is not the same as using keywords,
but is close. I even find the original paper at
http://www.literateprogramming.com/mccabe.pdf extremely confusing.

The word paths is used in two ways. One is as an edge in the graph, and the
other is as a set of edges, also called an independent circuit.  I will use
the terms edge (single edge) and path (independent circuit).

The appendix contains the technique using keywords. The flow graph for the
example SEARCH function looks like there are
12 edges - 11 nodes + 2 = 3 paths, but the text says
there are four. The code shows four, which matches the text, but there
are only three paths if only statements are counted that modify something.

I think one important point that is not defined in the original paper is
whether a group of statements modifies something, or is used later to
modify something.  This is particularly relevant to your question about
compound conditionals.

The question about compound conditionals (Meyers) is discussed here http://www.researchgate.net/publication/3407068_A_Critique_of_Cyclomatic_Complexity_as_a_Software_Metric in the
section named "Theoretical considerations". Compound conditionals are even more
tricky and important in a language like C or C++, since they have short-circuit evaluation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.

There can be a conditional like:

```
while(a==b && dofunction() {
}
```

The `dofunction()` will only execute if `a` is not equal to `b`.

For your last question about the for loop, I am assuming there is something
like:

```
statements (initial)
for(int i =0; i<12; i++)
    {
    statements (body)
    }
statements (end)
```

Sorry, it would be nice if I could draw a graph, but I do not have enough points.
I would place nodes like:

```
node(A)
    |
    | statements (initial)
    |
node(B)   (for loop)
    |                 |
    | no statements   |  statements (body)
    |                 |
node(C)   (meet point at end of for loop)
    |
    | statements (end)
    |
node(D)
```

A-B has one edge
B-C has two edges - one for the condition taken, and one for skipped.
C-D has one edge

There are only two paths through the code. The complexity is calculated as:
4 nodes - 4 edges + 2 = cyclomatic complexity of 2.

There is a document describing this here, and even more examples are
systematically analyzed.
http://oovaide.sourceforge.net/articles/Complexity.html.  This document
also shows that some tools count logical operators and some don't.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the links (as I assume you had intended them). pluss 1, and thank you for your wonderful contribution!

Comment: http://oovaide.sourceforge.net/articles/Complexity.html In Example 4, the CFG diagram and calculation seems to be not correct.  The direct edge from start to end seems to be unnecessary, because if and else paths of first condition are already noted.

Comment: Apologies for being so late but thanks so much, really helped clear things up for me!